# UnimplementedFeatureError: Variable inaccessible, too deep inside stack (17)

Tags: solidity, abiencoderv2

I'm getting this error, with no indication of which line of code or variable is responsible. I know it goes away when I comment out

```
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
```

…but I need ABIEncoderV2 as I have functions that return structs. The title above is the *entire* error message. Does anyone have any idea how I might go about looking for the variable responsible?

Comment: You can get rid of that pragma and then return the elements of the struct instead of the struct as a whole. The good news here is that it will force you to get rid of the pragma.

Comment: Can you show us your code? We can't help you without looking at it. Usually that error is caused because your code is too complex and it uses too many local variables, function parameters, return parameters.